# How to notice the situation when flash applet is being closed e.g. browser back button

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

How to catch up a situation when FLASH is forced to close e.g. because of BACK button click, 
 I need to make one HTTP call before that.

my code:

```
 stage.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE,unloadEvents,false,0,true);
```

I can see that FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT event occurs in that case, but CLOSE or UNLOAD focuses are not appearing?

Comment: I would go with help of JavaScript. Check this out: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Comment: I prefer changes to Flash module only, if possible to detect flash is being unload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javascript to protect from leaving the current page where your flash is located.
If user really wants to leave the page then make your http call, else just stay inside the page.

Here are some links... that should help:

[How to logout during onbeforeunload/onunload using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610950/how-to-logout-during-onbeforeunload-onunload-using-javascript)

[To execute Flex cleanup function when browser is closed by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647088/to-execute-flex-cleanup-function-when-browser-is-closed-by-user)

Comment: I dont want to protect from leaving, just need to receive event that flash is being closed now  so I can save data..

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible... else Javascript would be useless in my sample links. You are not the only one facing this...

Comment: thanks for links, window.onbeforeunload  seem to work with IE; but not with firefox. I have my SWF  file loaded with nested object + embed tags.

Comment: it may be that in NON-IE browsers the event to be called beforeunload and not with the 'on' in the front.

Comment: Thanks, it made a call but now firefox/chrome gives this error during my http call from flash during this "shutting down" event;
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: